# error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I have a problem with an android project, I made a project in my house and it runs well, but now, i have opened this project in another eclipse version and it doesn't works. I have a problem with the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar lib. I added the lib in this project with file -> import .But when i try to add the lib in properties->android-> add, the lib isn't there.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: add `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` from other projects to current project

Comment: This is my first time that I used this lib, I'm learning this :-(